# Node.js: Access db in called script

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a heroku scheduler job that runs every 10 minutes and calls the file expiration.js. This file is in the root folder right next to app.js.

expiration.js:

```
var app = require('./app.js');

function checkForExpiration() {
  var db = app.get('db');
  var collection = db.collection('postingcollection');
  // do stuff with collection that checks for expiration
}
checkForExpiration();
```

in my app.js file I have:

```
app = express();
//setup db with mongolab
app.set('db', db);
module.exports = app;
```

You might think that I am not setting up my db correctly, but it works everywhere else in my routes. I just cannot access it in this executed file. When the file is run I see this error:

```
2016-01-02T22:09:27.924443+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `node expiration` by scheduler@addons.heroku.com
2016-01-02T22:09:32.028186+00:00 heroku[scheduler.5884]: Starting process with command `node expiration`
2016-01-02T22:09:32.700417+00:00 heroku[scheduler.5884]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-02T22:09:34.312517+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154509+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]: /app/expiration.js:6
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154513+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:   var collection = db.collection('postingcollection');
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154514+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:                      ^
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154515+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154516+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154516+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:   at checkForExpiration (/app/expiration.js:6:22)
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154517+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:   at Object.<anonymous> (/app/expiration.js:52:1)
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154518+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:   at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154519+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154520+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154521+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:   at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154521+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154522+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:   at startup (node.js:138:18)
2016-01-02T22:09:35.154523+00:00 app[scheduler.5884]:   at node.js:974:3
```

It looks like var db is undefined therefore not the database.

My question is how can I access my app's database in this executable script?

Answer (score 0):

[`app.set` can only be used for internal settings.](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set)

You can instead use something like `app.locals.db` or just set `app.db`.